# If science value>6 link else if science value<6 different linkhow to do that

Tags: php, html

```
<td><a href="https://google.com"><?php echo $row['science']; ?></a></td>
```

If science value>6 link else if science value<6 different linkhow to do that

Comment: show  us your best attempt (code) so we can help you on your way

Comment: This appears to be database related. Relevant code and schema/values should be shown.

Comment: I was looking for that since your first answer didn't see it under the reputation button, thanks for reminder done accepting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff:

```
<td>
    <?php 
    if($row['science'] > 6) {
        echo '<a href="http://google.com">' . $row['science'] . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="http://bing.com">' . $row['science'] . '</a>';
    }
    ?>
</td>
```

NOTE: I made the second value "less than or equal to" 6 because if I had followed your question to the letter 6 would've been left out entirely.

Comment: thanks last question would be how do i display keep to display $row['science'] and not 'http://linkgreaterthan6' . I would like to display $row['science'] and make it clickable that would put me to 'http://linkgreaterthan6' 

Here's my attempt  echo '<a href="https://google.com">$row['science']</a>';

Comment: it's been 3 years since I studied php and html and I kind of don't have the time to re-study forgotten about basic stuffs as well been doin android lately that $row['science'] actually came from an android app edit text and inserts to phpmyadmin ,these questions are relevant to finish my project and speed things up
your answers really helped thanks. didnt know stackoverflow community were this responsive till i asked this first question. Thanks again everything worked out accordingly.